# Is there any package or component available for opening a Date Range in the button Using Angular?

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, calendar, primeng

I checked and referred many components for this but I am unable to find them.

[image]

Can anyone suggest and help if is there possible for a Date Range?

Comment: the more common are [material-angular](https://material.angular.io/) or [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), also [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) or [ng-zorro](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) or [nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/) or others, you can check e.g. this [link](https://www.decipherzone.com/blog-detail/angular-component-libraries) to see more options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Since you want to have a collapsible datepicker I've extended this datepicker-inline stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hsuszs

Besides the mat-datepicker Angular also offers a mat-calender which is a part of the datepicker component. With that you get a simple calender which you can show and hide with some basic animations like in the stackblitz. If you want to close the calender when clicking outside you would have to implement a function which for example gives some calender element focus and closes the calender when losing focus. Or you could listen on clicks outside of the calender.

Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. If you have further questions feel free to ask.

**Original:**
You can refer to the Angular Material Docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Don't forget to import the related modules:

`import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`

`import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';`

Comment: Thank you for your great reply,  I already tried that here is the example link => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v59qxb-pwqk1m?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.css. But, not want a popup. I need to display the calendar below the Date Range button 
like expand and collapse. It means When I click on the button It will expand the calendar and When I click on outside the button It will collapse the calendar.

Comment: Thank you, In mat-calendar It's fine. But Is it possible to get the date range to the mat calendar? like start date and end date?

Comment: I think this component does not work for me. I need a Date Range using this component like the Start date and End Date When Someone selects the date. It like one button click on the button it's opens the calendar and when the select the date It will get the start and end date